# Creating Custom WebPart -- RangeErrror / TypError trying to access data from a file

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-foundation, development, ajax

Hi I'm new to using SharePoint and I'm trying to transfer over an Employee Directory Search app from a website to SharePoint Foundation 2013.

I'm not able to use the same code in my .JS file and am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with it in SharePoint. Can anyone help me out?

I was able to `console.log` the data from my JSON file by removing `dataType: 'json'`and changing the `.json` filename to `.js` ... but I can't push the data into my `employees` array.

On my current website, the `Array.prototype.push.apply(employees, data)` works...but on SharePoint I am getting this error:

*`Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object`*

so I tried using `emploees.push(...data)` and I am getting this error:

*`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`*

**Here is the function I am having trouble with.**

```
function getADInfo(){
$.ajax({
    url: "/CustomWebparts/DirectorySearch/roster.js",
    method: 'GET',
    // dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success from getADInfo');
        // console.log(data);
        employees.push(...data);
        // Array.prototype.push.apply(employees, data);

        console.log(employees);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: If the contents of `roster.js` is JSON, have you tried making it `roster.txt` and then on the receiving end `var receivedJson = JSON.parse(data);` ?

Comment: @DylanCristy Ahh I thought I tried that earlier....thanks!

Comment: @DylanCristy I'm getting a different error now..would you know how to help?
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`  -- I'm trying to select an input field using `document.querySelector('.search');` for the eventlistener but its not working on sharepoint

Comment: @staysee you should raise this as another question and provide your existing code for your addEventListener call.

Comment: @staysee did my suggestion work to get you your JSON data successfully? Let me know, if so I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @DylanCristy Yes. That did help thank you. Post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contents of `roster.js` is just JSON, you could try making it `roster.txt` and then on the receiving end:

```
var receivedJson = JSON.parse(data);
```